# Converting px to em - text becomes smaller than original

Tags: html, css

Currently in the final stages of building a new website and have recently ran an accessibility checker. The checker is recommending changing my font sizes from px to em. 
However when I do a straight forward conversion (16px to 1em) the font becomes really small. Am I missing something?

Here is my styling.

```
.bodyText {font-size: 16px !important; padding-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;}
.bodyText a {color: #008080 !important; text-decoration: underline;}
.bodyText a:hover {color: #008080 !important;}
.bodyText li {font-size: 16px !important; color: #686868;}
.bodyText p {font-size: 16px !important; color: #686868;}
.bodyText p strong {color: #333333;}
```

All of this also sits in the body which has this attached.

```
body {font-size: 16px !important; font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif !important; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;}
tbody {font-size: 16px !important; font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif !important; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;}
```

Comment: Please share your markup

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the code needed to demonstrate your issue include HTML and CSS.  Use a snippet (CTRL-M when you edit) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 16 px is NOT 1em - well it CAN be, it can also be 2px or 200px it is just different.

Comment: Sorry, edited to show my css styling.

Comment: AND the markup please.  Also as soon as you start using `!important` (nearly always a bad idea) things get really messy to edit and manage.

Comment: `Am I missing something?` Yes you missing whole point of em. Try to google the purpose of technique before applying it.

Comment: try not to use `!important` so much - it should only be used as a last resort when trying to override an inline style, otherwise you will get into a css nightmare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let me say that EM is used locally and REM is used globally what do i mean with that?

Rem uses the html tag font-size so if:

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Then the `1 rem` is equal to `16px`

On the other hand when you use `em` you need to be context aware, meaning that if the parent container of the text element got `font-size: 12px` the `1em` becomes `12px`

You can read more about it here: https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/

Comment: "1 rem is equal to 16px"  - depends on the browser, most but not all.

Comment: Read the link i shared.

rem is read from html root tag, so as long if you define html to have font-size 16px then its 16 px. So i some obscure browser implements something else then override it with html fontsize 16

Comment: I think this might be my problem, I have no font size included in the html tag.

Comment: Here is the actual specification if you want to have a definitive source https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html

Comment: This solved the problem - thank you. I set my font-size in the html (originally as pixels but this also resulted in accessibility errors) as 100%, then I set the rest of my fonts throughout the site in em. All looks great and passes the accessibility check. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So em is not a size like px is. em refers to the current font-size set on an item,

so if

```
p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

then when you add in the em to a certain piece like say you have

```
<p class="em-class">Hello World</p>
<style>
.em-class {
 font-size: 2em;
 }
</style>
```

then your font-size would be 32px on that class. It essentially works as a % of the current font-size